# Are Express Sessions inherently unique to the visitor

Tags: node.js, express

I'm troubleshooting an issue with a server instance that  I need to do some root cause analysis and right now I believe the driver is Express Sessions.

I've implemented sessions as a primary intra-page data storage mechanism, but it seems that sessions are not unique to the visitor relationship.

By this I mean that I have a session that prefills a form on a "shipping information" page.  However, if I visit this page from other browsers or other machines the detail from the first session created on server start is prefilled as if the session data is bleeding into these other browser relationships.

So, I'm trying to understand if the intention for sessions is that they are unique to the visitor by default.  If not, can they be made to be unique?

I'm especially worried because admin authentication is also done via sessions.

Comment: Sorry, for clarity.. I'm not 100% that sessions is the driver of this issue, I'm also open to being told that sessions is not the issue and I will look for another root cause.

Comment: Yes they are unique to visitor, it sounds as if your code is setting some global state, and not sessions.   You may want to post the config you are using, plus where you are setting session vars.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation.  I've done deeper testing, and with your confirmation I'm confidant that sessions are not the problem.  It does appear to be a global issues.

Can you post your answer as an answer so I can approve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they are unique to visitor, it sounds as if your code is setting some global state, and not sessions. You may want to post the config you are using, plus where you are setting session vars.